# How to create SQL Server import template

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

For example I have daily Excel (xlsx) file, which I need to import every day in MS SQL Server Express 2014 which is located in localhost. Firstly Truncate the table.

How can I create some template to import Excel file into MS SQL server?

For example it will be in folder: `C:\Reports\1.xlsx`

For truncate I know the query:

```
USE [CompDB];
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Report_table];
GO
```

I tried to find in MSSQL Import - Export wizard some templates option, haven't found it there. Moreover, I tried to do this with Toad for SQL Server, but there are no templates available in free version.

**Or maybe you know how to do this with MySQL database?** It will be better choice for me.

Comment: For MS SQL use SSIS. For MySQL make a script which will convert it into CSV and then write stored procedure that will pull it. SSIS is the most preferable option in your case. It is dedicated for such things

Comment: If SSIS is available for MSSQL 2014 Express edition?

Comment: haven'r pay attention on the fact that you run on Express. As far as I know SSIS is not available for it. However, you can address your requirements with use of SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\file.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents)) on CSV file or find solution based on XML PATH

Answer (score 0):

Try the OLEDB approach

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\Data\Data.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

The parameters can vary depending on your Excel version, but I think this will work for you